# Call a File Inbound Endpoint via Http endpoint - Set XML as payload and update in IBM MQ

Tags: mule, ibm-mq, mule-component

I am designing an application flow where I have to read a file (XML File) and put the data into IBM MQ (Queue). Do I need to create an HTTP request that will trigger the File read and update queue, otherwise how do I perform this task.

Currently I am creating an HTTP Request and connecting it to WMQ but I am getting NULL data into the Queue. Basically the payload is NULL.

This is the data I read when I browse the Queue:
sr.org.mule.transport.NullPayload1.L5U���...xp

[image: App Flow]

[image: Message Data in the Queue]

Comment: Your question is confusing. Why start with a HTTP if you want to read a file? Why not just start with a file inbound?

Comment: If you don't want to access the file on-demand. Directly use File Inbound( Dont use HTTP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

[image]

Whenever you use File connector at any other place than the beginning of the flow, then it becomes an outbound endpoint.

For **using File as an inbound endpoint** to retrieve any file, you must **use it in the beginning of some flow & keep the flow in stopped state initially** as:

```
<flow name="filePickupFlow" initialState="stopped">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="src/main/resources/input" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
    <wmq:outbound-endpoint queue="gh" doc:name="WMQ" connector-ref="WMQ"/>
</flow>
```

For your case just change the path with your required file location.

Then for further **calling it via http, create another flow with http endpoint** &  use an **Expression component** to start the flow containing file inbound endpoint call as :

```
<expression-component doc:name="Expression">
    app.registry.filePickupFlow.start();
</expression-component>
```

Then **if you wish to stop it after it completes processing**, you can again use an **Expression component** as:

```
<expression-component doc:name="Expression">
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    app.registry.filePickupFlow.stop();
</expression-component>
```

Thread.sleep() is used here just to give some time gap between flow start & stop to let the flow operation complete. You can add some other thing for maintaing this time gap or set the time according to your own usage.

I guess this is what you were looking for.

Regards,

JJ

Comment: This really worked for me, thanks. But while I was able to pick the file up from the location, wmq was not able to read the data within the file. It read some random data and put it in MQ. I want to pass the data within the file to the MQ.

Comment: It didn't put any random data. Actually the output from File Inbound is of File Type, so you need to add a **File to String** transformer in between File endpoint & WMQ to make it readable in WMQ.

Comment: Thanks, @J J. It was ultra useful. Now if I have to move all the data within queue into another location as XML files do I need to create another flow  and how do I trigger that flow.

Comment: Yes, you need to create another flow with WMQ as the inbound endpoint & set its polling on after a specific time interval (for triggering that flow). It will check for any new queue entries & consume them whenever it polls.

Comment: @J J.  I am unable to poll the flow and I am getting the following error : `org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'wmq:inbound-endpoint'. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-outbound-endpoint, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":response}' is expected.`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the file component on-demand( Whenever you access the HTTP, only then File component needs to access), use `Mule Requester`  in the place of  file component which do the same work.

```
<mulerequester:config name="Mule_Requester" doc:name="Mule Requester"/>
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" basePath="test2" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<flow name="httpFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <mulerequester:request config-ref="Mule_Requester" resource="file://C:/in" doc:name="Mule Requester"/>
    <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
    <logger message="**payload:*#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Use WMQ here instead of Logger"/>

</flow>
```

Link to refer: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-module-requester/blob/master/mulerequesterdemo/src/main/app/MuleRequesterDemo.xml

Instead of HTTP, you can also schedule job trigger using Poll component based on your requirement. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You wanted to used file connector as inbound endpoint but actually using as outbound endpoint. Check your configuration xml file for file connector.

There are many ways for reading file as inbound like file connector, Poll scope or Quartz connector. You can use anyone of these as per you requirement. The simplest flow is as

```
<flow name="testfixedFlow">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="tmp" connector-ref="File" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
    <wmq:outbound-endpoint queue="xyz" connector-ref="WMQ" doc:name="WMQ"/>
</flow>
```

But if you want to get resource in between the flow you can use [Mule requester](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-module-requester)

Hope this helps.